# Gray code pattern looks like binary pattern. Is this correct?

Tags: matlab, gray-code

I have this following gray code pattern but it looks like binary pattern to me. Please let me know if this is correct or something has to be changed?

```py
n = ceil(log2(py));  T = length(n) ;
gray_pattrn = zeros(2^n,1) ;  gray_pattrn(2) = 1;  T = 2;
for  k = 2:n
   T2 = T+T ;
   gray_pattrn(T+1:T2) = T + flipud(gray_pattrn(1:T)) ;
   T = T2;  
end
mat = transpose(flip(transpose(de2bi(gray_pattrn))));

gray_level = 4; 
patternSeq = transpose(repmat(mat(:, gray_level), 1, 1024));
figure, imagesc(patternSeq); colormap gray;
figure, plot(patternSeq(512,:));
```

And I got the following images.

[image: Gray code pattern]
[image: Gray code at pixel 512]

Comment: Your example does not execute. How is `py` defined when you run it?

Comment: I am defining py as 1024. Size of the image as 1024x1024

Comment: Okay, and what are you trying to visualize? You're getting a valid Gray code listing, but you're only plotting the 4th bit of each pattern.

Comment: My idea is to use these gray codes to do phase unwrapping that is combined with sinusoidal pattern.If this is correct, then I hope i can do the unwrapping properly

Comment: Then, as the answer below states, this is a binary code so you're going to get a binary plot. Perhaps if you looked at each row of the Gray code pattern as a gray level? Something like `imagesc(gray_pattrn.')`?

Comment: Thats what I have shown in the figure above the plot.

Comment: I was suggesting `gray_pattrn` rather than `patternSeq`.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the name, [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) is binary and so what you are getting could very well be correct (I haven't actually checked your code). It's called Gray code because it was invented by Frank Gray, *not* because it outputs grayscale values (it doesn't).